# Is it correct to execute two commands in CMD directive of Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

I need to run two commands via `CMD` directive in my Dockerfile like the following:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/project
CMD ["/sbin/my_init", "node", "server.js"]
```

Is the approach mentioned above correct?

As I understand Docker's container approach - each container lives as long as the parent process is running. But if run two ones which is the parent in this case?

Comment: Does that even work?

Comment: Yes it works fine but I'm not sure about the approach

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not the correct way to this.

What are you actively trying to do here?

If you're trying to run multiple processes, consider using something like [supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/)

However, the implication from your example is that you're trying to use some kind of init system for your cmd. If that's the case, consider using something like [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) or [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini), which you can use as your entrypoint:

```
WORKDIR /var/www/project
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```